# array is printed as a string in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How does react work with arrays while we try to print them?

```js
class App extends Component {
        constructor() {
          this.state = { 
            myarr: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
          };
        }
        render(){
          return <div>{this.state.myarr}</div> 
          // it prints 12345.... I am able to understand why???
        } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: `console.log` has no relation to `React`. console output are associated to browser.

Comment: `console.log(this.state.myarr);`

Comment: updated the questions by removing typos... please can you tell me the reason now

Comment: Downvotes are probably because you can probably find this answer easily by a little more research, or in another question asked in stackoverflow. Didn't downvote because you're new to stackoverflow, just be more careful and take a look at the https://stackoverflow.com/conduct. Happy coding :)

Comment: I am using latest version of react. console.log(myarr) in componentDidMount ==> is returning the array not strings. could you recheck ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just want to show the array as array.

You can use `JSON.stringify(array)`. Like

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'/>
```

why your code prints `12345` because you are making it do it. Anything inside `{..}` expression shows its value

Comment: yp I understand that it prints value.. but myarr value is [1,2,3,4,5] ... isnt it??

Answer (score 0):

When you try to print an array, it's best to use .map() function.

While using map, make sure to give every item a unique 'index' value. Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

```
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
          {this.state.myarr.map((number) => (
            <li key={number.toString()}>
              {number}
            </li>
            ))}
        </div>);
    }
```

It can really help to study ES6 class methods before learning react, and then reading the official documentation. You probably don't even have to keep that array in a state.

[This link](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) may help you understand better.

Comment: but my question was not this... I want to know why does it print 12345 instead of [1,2,3,4,5] as a result for the code that i have written

Comment: You are trying to directly print an array inside a div without iterating over it, or using alternative methods like JSON.stringify(array) as george suggested. I don't know the  exact reason, but it seems the array value is printed without being seperated by commas, unlike pure javascript where it's printed seperated by commas by default. For it to print 1,2,3,4,5 you should add a seperator like .join(,). The reason for this can be the JSX or ES6 class syntax rules.

Comment: Your array values are 1,2,3,4,5 by the way. For it to print [1,2,3,4,5] in array format, use george's answer.